# Update PL/SQL block inside procedure, which I'm using in web project, is taking too long

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I've written PL/SQL code for updating columns of table, based on passed input from front end application e.g. if `INSTTABLE = 8` then following block will run. I've 90+ applications like this and running update inside procedure.During testing it in `dev environment`, Although code is working fine and doing intended job which is to set columns values to zero first and then call few functions to do financial calculations, it is taking too long *(more than an hour)*. Initially I thought it is because of many millions of rows/data but I am posting it here to check whether there is any further improvement is possible in code to reduce execution time.

Thanks in advance for kind help!

PS: I can't make changes to functions, such as `BAS2_RWA_CALC` internal calc/return value because it is being used by many other procs in prod, hence I did set columns to 0, in seperate update statement, before doing main update. Reason for setting it to zero is that production is following same logic of setting columns to 0 first and then doing calculations. If I don't do so, there is difference in comparison query.

```
--explain plan for update set values to zero
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |               | 25545 |  4365K|  1383   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE            | MORT_BACK_SEC |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MORT_BACK_SEC | 25545 |  4365K|  1383   (1)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--Explain plan for merge
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT      |               |     1 |  2605 |  1541   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE               | MORT_BACK_SEC |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW               |               |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN         |               |     1 |  2498 |  1541   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| RPT_ACCT_HIER |     1 |   491 |   156   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| MORT_BACK_SEC | 25545 |    48M|  1384   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
IF INSTTABLE = 8 THEN 

--Block to set columns to zero value

  UPDATE usb.MORT_BACK_SEC SET
        BAS_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_AB_RWA = 0, BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT = 0, BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT = 0, IMP_BAS_EB_RWA = 0, IMP_BAS_AB_RWA = 0, IDS_BAS_EB_RWA = 0, 
        IDS_BAS_AB_RWA = 0, DIS_BAS_EB_RWA = 0, DIS_BAS_AB_RWA = 0, PRE_BAS_EB_RWA = 0, PRE_BAS_AB_RWA = 0, BAS_AIR_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_AIR_AB_RWA = 0, 
        BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_RWA = 0, BAS_TPR_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_TPR_AB_RWA = 0, BAS_UNR_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_UNR_AB_RWA = 0, 
        BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_ICAAP_AIR_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_ICAAP_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_ICAAP_DIS_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_ICAAP_IDS_EB_RWA = 0, 
        BAS_ICAAP_IMP_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_ICAAP_PRE_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_ICAAP_TPR_EB_RWA = 0, BAS_ICAAP_UNR_EB_RWA = 0, IMP_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, 
        IMP_BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, IDS_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, IDS_BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, DIS_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, DIS_BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, 
        PRE_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, PRE_BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, BAS_AIR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, BAS_AIR_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, 
        BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, BAS_TPR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, BAS_TPR_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, 
        BAS_UNR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, BAS_UNR_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = 0, IMP_BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, IMP_BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, IDS_BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, 
        IDS_BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, DIS_BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, DIS_BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, PRE_BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, PRE_BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, 
        BAS_AIR_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, BAS_AIR_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, 
        BAS_TPR_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, BAS_TPR_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, BAS_UNR_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0, BAS_UNR_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = 0
    WHERE AS_OF_DATE = TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY');

    COMMIT;

   MERGE INTO ( SELECT /*+ index(a idx1) */ D.*,
       CASE WHEN GL_ACCOUNT_ID IN (1370050, 1450035) THEN 0 
       ELSE USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) END AS V_BAS_EB_RWA,
       CASE WHEN GL_ACCOUNT_ID IN (1370050, 1450035) THEN 0 
       ELSE USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) END AS V_BAS_AB_RWA,
       0 AS V_BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT,
       0 AS V_BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (IMP_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (IMP_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_IMP_BAS_AB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (IDS_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_IDS_BAS_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (IDS_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_IDS_BAS_AB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (DIS_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_DIS_BAS_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (DIS_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_DIS_BAS_AB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (PRE_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_PRE_BAS_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (PRE_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_PRE_BAS_AB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (AIR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_AIR_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (AIR_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_AIR_AB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (DELAY_REC_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (DELAY_REC_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (TPR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_TPR_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (TPR_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_TPR_AB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (UNR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_UNR_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (UNR_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_UNR_AB_RWA,
       CASE WHEN GL_ACCOUNT_ID IN (1370050, 1450035) THEN 0 
       ELSE USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) END AS V_BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (AIR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_AIR_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (DELAY_REC_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (DIS_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_DIS_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (IDS_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_IDS_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (IMP_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_IMP_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (PRE_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_PRE_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (TPR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_TPR_EB_RWA,
       USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (UNR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K, 0), 0.06, 0.08) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_UNR_EB_RWA
           FROM USB.MORT_BACK_SEC D ) A
   USING (SELECT * FROM USB.rpt_acct_hier) B
       ON (a.gl_account_id = b.acct_member and a.as_of_date = TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and b.acct_gen2 = 'a1000')
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
       BAS_EB_RWA = V_BAS_EB_RWA,
       BAS_AB_RWA = V_BAS_AB_RWA,
       BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT = V_BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT,
       BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT = V_BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT,
       IMP_BAS_EB_RWA = V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA,
       IMP_BAS_AB_RWA = V_IMP_BAS_AB_RWA,
       IDS_BAS_EB_RWA = V_IDS_BAS_EB_RWA,
       IDS_BAS_AB_RWA = V_IDS_BAS_AB_RWA,
       DIS_BAS_EB_RWA = V_DIS_BAS_EB_RWA,
       DIS_BAS_AB_RWA = V_DIS_BAS_AB_RWA,
       PRE_BAS_EB_RWA = V_PRE_BAS_EB_RWA,
       PRE_BAS_AB_RWA = V_PRE_BAS_AB_RWA,
       BAS_AIR_EB_RWA = V_BAS_AIR_EB_RWA,
       BAS_AIR_AB_RWA = V_BAS_AIR_AB_RWA,
       BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA = V_BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA,
       BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_RWA = V_BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_RWA,
       BAS_TPR_EB_RWA = V_BAS_TPR_EB_RWA,
       BAS_TPR_AB_RWA = V_BAS_TPR_AB_RWA,
       BAS_UNR_EB_RWA = V_BAS_UNR_EB_RWA,
       BAS_UNR_AB_RWA = V_BAS_UNR_AB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_AIR_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_AIR_EB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_DIS_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_DIS_EB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_IDS_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_IDS_EB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_IMP_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_IMP_EB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_PRE_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_PRE_EB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_TPR_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_TPR_EB_RWA,
       BAS_ICAAP_UNR_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_UNR_EB_RWA,            

       IMP_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
       IMP_BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_IMP_BAS_AB_RWA, 0), 2),
       IDS_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_IDS_BAS_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
       IDS_BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_IDS_BAS_AB_RWA, 0), 2),
       DIS_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_DIS_BAS_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
       DIS_BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_DIS_BAS_AB_RWA, 0), 2),
       PRE_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_PRE_BAS_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
       PRE_BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_PRE_BAS_AB_RWA, 0), 2),
       BAS_AIR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_BAS_AIR_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
       BAS_AIR_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_BAS_AIR_AB_RWA, 0), 2),
       BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
       BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_RWA, 0), 2),

       BAS_TPR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_BAS_TPR_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
       BAS_TPR_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_BAS_TPR_AB_RWA, 0), 2),
       BAS_UNR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_BAS_UNR_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
       BAS_UNR_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_BAS_UNR_AB_RWA, 0), 2),
       -- CALCULATE BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS AND  BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS
       IMP_BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (IMP_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       IMP_BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (IMP_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       IDS_BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (IDS_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       IDS_BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (IDS_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       DIS_BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (DIS_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       DIS_BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (DIS_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       PRE_BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (PRE_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       PRE_BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (PRE_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       BAS_AIR_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (AIR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       BAS_AIR_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (AIR_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0,BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       BAS_DELAY_REC_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (DELAY_REC_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       BAS_DELAY_REC_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (DELAY_REC_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),

       BAS_TPR_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (TPR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       BAS_TPR_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (TPR_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       BAS_UNR_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (UNR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0),
       BAS_UNR_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = USB.BAS2_EL_CALC (UNR_AVG_BOOK_BAL, 0, BAS_PD, BAS_LGD, 0)
       WHERE
           (AS_OF_DATE = TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
COMMIT; 

END IF;


--Function: BAS_RWA_CALC logic

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USB."BAS2_RWA_CALC" (v_formula in char,v_bal in number,v_k_factor in number, v_bas_min in number,v_rwa_adj_rate in number) return number

 is

v_rwa number(15,2);

begin

v_rwa := nvl(v_bal,0)*nvl(v_k_factor,0)/nvl(v_bas_min,0);
v_rwa := v_rwa*(1+v_rwa_adj_rate);
return round(v_rwa,2);

end;
/


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7ikw.png
```

Comment: Three questions: 1) Do you know which part of the code is slow?  Is it the `UPDATE`, the join of the `MERGE`, or the calls to the functions?  2) What version of Oracle are you using?  3) If the functions are the slow parts, can you post the top of the functions?  If you're on 12c, and can't significantly change the logic, adding a `PRAGMA UDF;` may significantly improve performance.  And if the arguments are repetitive, enabling result cache might help.

Comment: @JonHeller:  **1)** It's multiple function calling. Function has 3-4 lines of code and I would to replace it in update but I've been told to use function calls so can't replace it in code. ```Fyi: I've updated question and also included functions in here.    2)   ```Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production```  **3)** ```It's been suggested by some developers to use PRAGMA UDF when calling function from SQL. I'm not sure if it's being used in some other PL/SQL proc, Would you suggest to place PRAGMA UDF anyway or sth else needs to be included?```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to reduce the overhead of the context switches between SQL and PL/SQL.

1. **`PRAGMA UDF;`**  After the first `is`, add `pragma udf;` to the code to tell Oracle to optimize the function for SQL.  In my quick testing this reduced context switching overhead by 60% in SQL calls.  The problems with this approach is that it requires modifying the function for everybody, and it may incur a performance penalty when called in PL/SQL.
2. **Wrapper function with `PRAGMA UDF;`** If you can't directly modify the function, create new functions on top of the old functions, created them with `pragma udf;`, and call those functions in the SQL.  My tests indicate this can reduce context switching by 52%, which isn't as good as the previous solution, but it's pretty close.  This approach keeps all the original logic in the same place, thus preserving the do-not-repeat-yourself rule.  It does however create new objects.
3. **PL/SQL `WITH` function** Create the wrapper function as a common table expression in the SQL statement.  This can reduce overhead by roughly 32%.  It's a pure-SQL approach, but it's not as fast as other solutions, and the SQL statement will look ugly.

These won't work for you, but for future readers it's worth noting that the best options are:

1. Move the procedural PL/SQL code inside the declarative SQL code.
2. Change the PL/SQL interfaces to accept bulk data, such as collections, cursor, table name for dynamic SQL, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your MERGE statement you've got 59 function calls. That's a lot. It looks like you're calling 'BAS2_RWA_CALC' 27 times for every row in `MORT_BACK_SEC`, even if you don't use the results of those calls. Now, it may be that the database is smart enough to only make those calls for the rows you actually end up using from `MORT_BACK_SEC`, but I wouldn't count on that. If they're not needed elsewhere (and I don't see that they are) I suggest pushing those calculations into the `WHEN MATCHED` block.

You're also calling `BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL` and `BAS2_EL_CALC` 16 times for every update that gets made. I have no idea how complex these functions are but if they're simple and can be replaced by an inline `CASE` expression or the like I'd do that, because that number of function calls are going to kill the performance of this statement. I don't know what kind of plan this is generating, but I doubt it matters - I suspect that the run time of the statement will be dominated by the execution time of all those function calls.

I'd try to rearrange your `MERGE` statement for you but I don't know which function parameters are columns in `MORT_BACK_SEC` and which ones are variables defined outside the `MERGE` statement. Try to factor as many function calls as you can out of the statement itself, if any of them can be, and certainly get them out of the initial `MERGE` table. IMO your `MERGE` should start with

```
MERGE INTO MORT_BACK_SEC a
  USING RPT_ACCT_HIER b
    ON (a.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = b.ACCT_MEMBER AND
        a.AS_OF_DATE = V_DATE AND
        b.ACCT_GEN2 = 'a1000')
```

and then take it from there.

Of course, since you don't have a `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT`, you could re-do this as an `UPDATE` instead of a `MERGE` once you get all those function calls moved into the `UPDATE` block. It's up to you. But again, I doubt it matters as those function calls are where I suspect that this statement spends its time.

Comment: Hi @Bob Jarvis: Thanks for the detailed reply ```Variables, in my update block, always start with v_```, hence ```V_BASEL_MIN and V_BAS_RWA_RATE``` are variables inside ```MERGE INTO (....) A using... These variables have fixed values which are 0.06 and 0.08 respectively.``` Also, I can't replace function with the inline statements because it'll make the code too complex/long as well as it'll remove consistency along with few other reasons.

Comment: Also, the reason I did it this way because ```..._TOTAL_CAPITAL fields are using ```calculated RWA fields (done inside MERGE into(...) block). ```For instance, V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA, calculated inside MERGE into (...) block, is being used in function BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL() for calculating  IMP_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL.```

Comment: May I ask you to show an example for a few of the fields' update statement *(e.g. for the one I gave example in the above comment, ```V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA and IMP_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL```)* using your way? Afterward, I'll update the entire proc and test it at my end to see the performance difference.